# Android - Showing Alert Dialog leads to BadTokenException in Service class

Tags: java, android, service, gps

I am reading GPS info and sending it to the network every 10 seconds.

What I am doing is using an handler which runs my service class **GPSTracker**

```
public void startGpsService() {
        handler = new Handler();
        task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());

                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    ... do something
                } else {
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

                handler.postDelayed(task, 10000);
            }
        };
        task.run();
    }
```

if my GPS setting are not enabled **gps.showSettingsAlert();** is executed

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; 
    double longitude; 
    double speed; 
    public double altitude; 


    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get altitude
     * */
    public double getAltitude(){
        if(location != null){
            altitude = location.getAltitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return altitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get velocity
     * */
    public double getVelocity(){
        if(location != null){
            speed = location.getSpeed();
        }

        // return longitude
        return speed;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

My problem is that **alertDialog.show();** raises this exception:

> 08-21 09:49:23.906: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{...}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
>   Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

How to solve it? Similar solutions found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032316/dialog-issue-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343393/badtokenexception) dont fix my problem as in that case it happens inside activity classes.

Comment: post the whole `GPSTracker` class

Comment: just added the full code for GPSTracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog can not be shown without activity. Your code shows dialog with applicationContext, so it will cause error.

try this below:

```
 /**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(Activity activity){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant really create a dialog in the service but you can use the system alert dialog from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918571/how-to-display-a-dialog-from-a-service) bottom answer.

He said that you need add the type of dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

and also you need permission for it to enable you to use it in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Now this is only if you really need a dialog, but I wont really recommend dialog within the service.

You can use toast instead.

Comment: I do need a dialog because I need to show the possibility of changing settings or not ...